# I want to load my main code every 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a windows form app that display restaurant orders. I want to load the code every 5 seconds to check if there is a new order to display.

I have a timer created in the form designer:

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What exactly you want to do every 5 seconds? Move that code into a method and call that method from timer event handler.

Comment: the question is how to load the main code (not a method) every seconds

Comment: You should reconsider your terminology. What exactly do you define to be your "main code"?

Comment: I have a public form1()  thats what i want to call every 5 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public void DisplayRestaurantOrder()
    {
        //Display restaurant order here
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRestaurantOrder();
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (true)//check new order
        {
            DisplayRestaurantOrder();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Set the timer's `Interval` property to 5000 (`milliseconds`)

2) Create a method which loads the data e.g.

```cs
private void LoadOrders()
{
   // ... do stuff here
}
```

3) In the timer's `Tick` event handler make a call to the load method, in this case `LoadOrders`:

```cs
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadOrders();
}
```

4) In the `Form.Load` event do `timer1.Start();`, and maybe also a initial call to the load method, to make a `Form.Load` event handler just double click the form:

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //LoadOrders(); //this is the initial load call.

    //timer1.Start();
}
```

as a result you should have something like this:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadOrders();

        timer1.Start();
    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadOrders();
    }

    private void LoadOrders()
    {
       // ... do stuff here
    }
}
```

**UPDATE (sins the OP wants to load what is in the constructor):**

If what is needed to be loaded, is in the `Form1` constructor then just move everything from in there to a new method and make a call to that method in both the `timer1_Tick` handler and in the constructor itself, e.g.:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();

    Load();
}

//should be kept as to start the timer.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load();
}

private void Load()
{
   //InitializeComponent(); //this shouldn't be called more than once as it can create duplicate objects, i.e. buttons, menu strips, etc.

   // ... do other stuff here
}
```